# Difference between $OPTIND and $#

Tags: shell, shell-script, getopts

Hey is there any difference between `$OPTIND` and `$#`?
Is there a certain reason for that you use `$OPTIND` with getopts, not `$#`?

Comment: Assume you run your program with "myprogram -a -b -c one two three".  How do you split out "one", "two", and "three"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$OPTIND` indicates how far you have progressed through parsing the parameter list (i.e., for options), while `$#` is simply the number of parameters. They are not really related, because `$OPTIND` changes, while `$#` does not (unless you use `shift`).

The POSIX description of [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/getopts.html) goes into some detail.

Comment: When I used `shift $((OPTIND-1)`, then `$OPTIND` didn't changed but `$#` changed. That made the difference clear for me. Thank you ! :)